# Custom ADV ble frame, stm32wb55

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, frame, sensors

I am working with stm32wb55 on a ble project, is it possible to create my own adv frame that can be updated periodically, for example every 10 seconds, as I am trying to send sensor data on a ble frame but I don't know where to start or how can I create a ble frame that changes every time period.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow! Have you read the [documentation](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32wb55rg.html#documentation)? If you have a question about your code, we are happy to answer it here. Maybe you should first take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), because your question seems a little [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yes you can do this, look for example BLE "beacon" projects.  This question as it is however isn't specific enough to be answered.